# Homebrew complains about a non-Homebrew "pkg-config" in my PATH

Tags: macos, package-management, homebrew

I've just installed Homebrew onto my machine, after which I ran `brew doctor` which threw up two warnings.

I didn't appear to have the command line tools for Xcode installed, which I have now. The second warning is:

```
Warning: You have a non-Homebrew 'pkg-config' in your PATH:
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/pkg-config

`./configure` may have problems finding brew-installed packages using
this other pkg-config.
```

What can I do to remedy this?

Comment: Where does `/opt/sm`, or the `pkg-config` come from? Do you have any other package manager installed perhaps (I'm not familiar with those, just Homebrew)? Do you remember installing it there?

Comment: no idea, its a brand new machine, i decided to add all the programs on by hand instead of from a backup to get rid of all the stuff i didnt need

Comment: the only thing i could think of is it may have came bundeled with either osx, xcode, xcode command line tools, or when i installed rails from railsinstaller.org

Comment: It's the Rails installer that put itself in `/opt/sm/`, including the `pkg-config` installation, which now takes precendence over the default `pkg-config` from Homebrew in `/usr/local/bin`. Do you see any modifications the Rails installer might have made to `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile`, `/etc/paths.d/`, etc. to modify the path?

Comment: sorry slhck, were should i be look for those ?

Comment: Those are paths to actual files. Since you installed Homebrew I assumed you were a little familiar with the command line, sorry. You have to open them, e.g. with `open -e ~/.bash_profile`, or use the Finder to go to `/etc/paths.d` through *Go » Go to Folder…*. It's very likely the Rails installer has set its path somewhere there.

Comment: thanks for help with this slhck, ive ran `open -e ~/.bash_profile` and `open -e ~/.profile` with both i got "The file ______ dose not exits" i also navigated to /ect/paths.d but the folder was empty does that sound correct ?

Comment: Ah, that simply means Rails installer modified the path somewhere else. Last try: In the terminal enter `touch ~/.bash_profile`, then try opening it again, and add the line: `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` – now restart Terminal and run `brew doctor` again.

Comment: no luck unfortunately, i get the same warning. Although i was just reading up this article on engine yard - (https://www.engineyard.com/blog/2012/railsinstaller-for-os-x/) were it says that with the stuff railinstaller installs "OS/X users won’t need to use a different package manager such as Homebrew or MacPorts for most common gems." Although i not quite sure how you would install gems

Comment: Through `gem install` presumably? That should work as usual. Do you need Homebrew for anything else? I mean, you could just ignore the warning until you run into actual compilation problems.

Comment: yeh, i think thats what ill end up doing. Thanks for the help